# How to a hide a page

Tags: apache, cakephp

I have a pop up that is called through a java script, the same pop up without a JavaScript is an ctp page in cakephp. How can I hide that page from users and search engines going to access it like: /users/register

Is there anything that can be done in .htaccess or cakephp to prevent access to it through /users/register

Comment: Prevent access, or prevent SEs from indexing?

Answer (score 1):

Remove register.ctp file from users folder and create one in ajax folder `users/ajax/register.ctp`, then use **[RequestHandler](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#checking-request-conditions)** component to inspect request type:

```
public function register()
{
  if($this->request->is('ajax')){
    // add registration code here
  } else {
   //Throw new error
  }

}
```

Comment: I am not that expert in Cakephp, so what is the right code to fix this, where I should add the cakephp code? the register file is a register.ctp file.

Comment: The JS pop up stopped working, saying content could not be found.